# Difference between a.out and ./a.out

Tags: linux, terminal

**My Confusion**

`a.out` is the output of the programs which I execute in my Ubuntu 12.10.
In Red Hat system when I execute `a.out` in the terminal it executes. While in Ubuntu I have to execute `./a.out` to get the output. 'a.out' doesn't work.

Can somebody explain what is the difference between the commands?

Comment: +1 Not sure why this valid question was down voted.

Comment: Wait, redhat includes `./` in `$PATH` by default? *Ewwwwww*...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The behaviour you experience depends most likely on differences in the environment variable `$PATH`. The `$PATH` is essentially a colon-separated list of directories, which are searched in order for a particular executable when a program is invoked using an`exec` operating system call. The `$PATH` can contain relative path components, typically `.` or an empty string, which both refer to the current working directory. If the current directory is part of `$PATH`, files in the current working directory can be executed by just their name, e.g. `a.out`. If the current directory is not in `$PATH`, one must specify a relative or absolute path to the executable, e.g. `./a.out`.

Having relative path components in `$PATH` has potential security implications as executables in directories earlier in `$PATH` overshadow executables in directories later in the list. Consider for example an attack on a system where the current working directory path `.` preceeds `/bin` in `$PATH`. If an attacker manages to place a malicious script sharing a name with a commonly used system utility, for instance `ls`, in the current directory (which typically is far easier that replacing binaries in root-owned `/bin`), the user will inadvertently invoke the malicious script when the intention is to invoke the system `ls`. Even if `.` is only appended at the end of `$PATH`, a user could be tricked to inadvertently invoke an executable in the current directory which shares a name with a common utility not found on that particular system. This is why it is common **not** to have relative path components as part of the default `$PATH`.

Comment: Hey thomas..
I am trying to execute a.out in Unbuntu 12.10 from the same file it is stored. But still it doesn't work. I have to use ./a.out unlike in redhat.

Comment: If you do `echo $PATH` on each of the systems you should see `.` as part of of the `PATH` on Red Hat, but not on the Ubuntu system. If you want the same behaviour on Ubuntu you could append `.` to the `PATH` on Ubuntu with the command `export PATH=$PATH:.` (add `PATH=$PATH:.` to `~/.profile` to make the change permanent), but be aware that this has certain security implications which I try to explain in the edited answer.

Comment: +1 for the security warning of having `./` in `$PATH`. It's a bad idea from a security point of view and it encourages sloppy behavior you really don't need.

Comment: hi thomas.... `echo $PATH` in red hat has no `.` in the end of the path name as you said `echo $PATH` gave me this in fact `/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin::/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/clien t_1/bin:/home/H11/u756938/bin` and a.out is still working...

Comment: @MunaiDasUdasin: What does `command -v a.out` output on the Red Hat system?

Comment: `command -v a.out` in Redhat gives `./a.out`.... It gives nothing in Ubuntu. `command -v ./a.out` gives `./a.out` in Ubuntu.

Comment: Both `.` and an empty string in `$PATH` refer to the current directory. Note the `::` after `/usr/bin` in the output of `echo $PATH`.